# How to check if a soup contains an element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html. I would like to check if it contains at least one `English` section. This is signified by

```
<summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="English">English</h2></summary>
```

This operation is performed millions of times. To be efficient, I want checking process stops right after it meets the first of such elements. I tried a method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262945/7357673). Could you please elaborate on

- why `soup.find('details[data-level="2"]:has(h2#English)')` did not work? On the other hand, `soup.select_one('details[data-level="2"]:has(h2#English)')` works perfectly.
- how to solve it?

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

texte = """
<div id="bodyContent" class="content mw-parser-output">
    <div id="mw-content-text" style="direction: ltr;">
        <h1 class="section-heading" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" data-section-id="0">
            <span class="mw-headline" id="title_0">pomme</span>
        </h1>     
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="English">English</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="French">French</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')

if soup.find('details[data-level="2"]:has(h2#English)'):  
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: why you just didn't find element With id?

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili There are millions of such html. To be stable, I would impose a strict condition `details[data-level="2"]:has(h2#English)` rather than just With id.

Comment: Instead of `find`, use `select` [`see this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033910/4985099)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `select_one` instead of `find`. Something like this.

```
soup.select_one('details[data-level="2"] summary.section-heading h2#English')
```

The result will be

```
<h2 id="English">English</h2>
```

Comment: And to answer "why find not working like this `soup.find('details[data-level="2"]:has(h2#English)')` ". Basically you can't search by CSS-selectors with it.

[Here more info](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_all` and then search what you wish for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

texte = """
<div id="bodyContent" class="content mw-parser-output">
    <div id="mw-content-text" style="direction: ltr;">
        <h1 class="section-heading" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" data-section-id="0">
            <span class="mw-headline" id="title_0">pomme</span>
        </h1>     
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="English">English</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="French">French</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')
details = soup.find_all("details", {"data-level": "2"})
lang = "English"
for detail in details:
    detail_str = str(detail)
    if lang in detail_str:
        print(detail)
```

Outputs:

```
<details data-level="2" open="">
<summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="English">English</h2></summary>
<details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `BeautifulSoup` doesn't have xpath support, we can use `lxml` alternatively.

```py
from lxml import html
texte = """
<div id="bodyContent" class="content mw-parser-output">
    <div id="mw-content-text" style="direction: ltr;">
        <h1 class="section-heading" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" data-section-id="0">
            <span class="mw-headline" id="title_0">pomme</span>
        </h1>     
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="English">English</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
        <details data-level="2" open="">
            <summary class="section-heading"><h2 id="French">French</h2></summary>
            <details data-level="3" open="">abc</details>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>
"""
tree = html.fromstring(texte)
element = tree.xpath('//details[@data-level="2"]//h2[contains(text(),"English")]')
if element:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```